# How do I put a Flex Air App on a separate desktop window?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I want to have 2 windows, one on the main desktop and another on a separate desktop window.
I can't find this in the documentation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what i was after was the Screens array as described here

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a47e0-8000.html

Comment: I recommend re-writing your question to be more clear; so that this is an appropriate answer to the correct question.  It will potentially help future users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) to add a new window in your Adobe AIR Desktop Application.  A single NativeWindow is already created as part of your [WindowedApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/WindowedApplication.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yep it's possible use the Window class
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Window.html

all Windows are stored in NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows

so you can do stuff like this

```
for (var i:int =
   NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows.length - 1; i > 0;
   --i)             { NativeWindow(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows[i]).close();
   }
```